# OSX Applescript - Specify generic local user directory

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm looking to create an applescript that will run across our office and copy a select file to co-workers users/co-workersusername/library/application support/adobe/cameraraw directory. Is there a generic alias so i can copy the file to whatever the current users library is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a standard Unix shortcut to access the user's home folder:

```
set path_ to "~/Library/Application Support/..."
```

The preceding `~` is shorthand for the user's home directory (equivalent to the `$HOME` environment variable)

Comment: This solution has problems when you use `POSIX file` of the path: Then `~` is not recognized.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
set adobeCameraRawFolderPath to (((path to application support from user domain)
                    as string) & "Adobe:CameraRaw:") as alias
```

To get the POSIX path:

```
set posixAdobeCameraRawFolderPath to POSIX path of adobeCameraRawFolderPath
```